# Dafny difference between seq<int> and array<int>

Tags: arrays, sequence, dafny

- I can't seem to tell the difference between dafny's  `seq<int>` and `array<int>`.
- Do they correspond to their SMT entities? (not sure because arrays in dafny have `.Length`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sequence is a (n immutable) mathematical list. An array is a heap allocated (mutable, potentially aliased) data structure.

Consider the following two silly methods

```
method Seq()
{
  var x := [1, 2, 3];
  assert x[1] == 2;
  var y := x;
  assert y[1] == 2;
  y := y[1 := 7];
  assert y[1] == 7;
  assert x[1] == 2;
}

method Array()
{
  var x := new int[3](i => i + 1);
  assert x[1] == 2;
  var y := x;
  assert y[1] == 2;
  y[1] := 7;
  assert y[1] == 7;
  assert x[1] == 7;
}
```

The first method uses sequences. Since sequences are immutable, `y` gets updated to a *new* sequence, with index 1 updated to have value 7. As expected, `x` remains unchanged throughout the manipulation of `y`.

The second method uses arrays. Since arrays are heap allocated and can alias, when we assign `y := x`, we enter a world where `x` and `y` are two different names for the same array in the heap. That means that if we modify the array via `y`, we will see the results reflected in reads through `x`.

To answer your second question, Dafny-level sequences and arrays do not directly correspond to the SMT-level things of the same name. Dafny's encoding does not use SMT-level sequences or arrays at all. Instead, everything is encoded via uninterpreted functions. I think this is primarily for historical reasons, and I don't know off the top of my head whether anyone has seriously investigated the SMT theory of sequences in the context of Dafny. I can say that the current encoding has been pretty carefully tuned for solver performance.